I can't install Viber, after installing it doesn't open
Selecting previously unselected package viber.
(Reading database ... 151326 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack viber.deb ...
Unpacking viber (21.8.0.11) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of viber:
 viber depends on libxcb-xinput0; however:
  Package libxcb-xinput0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package viber (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1.1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.27-2build1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 viber


Alternatively, you can try Viber AppImage like this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1527954/1157209

Whatever command you used to try to install viber.deb in 24.04 it was not a command of the form sudo apt install ./viber.deb which would have installed viber's required dependencies automatically. libxcb-xinput0 package is not installed which is creating dependency problems, so install it manually.
sudo apt install libxcb-xinput0

Then try to install viber.deb again.

In my Ubuntu 24.04, I had the same error and I managed to install Viber with the following:
sudo apt install ./viber.deb --fix-broken

